# Can a browser re-open a downloaded file rather than downloading the file each time it gets requested?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, download

Here's the scenario. We have a table with a list of PDFs that are all pretty large (250mb each). In some cases, our links in the table go to the same PDF (but different pages).

Currently, when a user clicks on a link for a PDF, the browser downloads a new copy of the PDF. So if there are three links to three different pages in the same PDF, the browser will download all 250mb of the PDF fresh each time.

What we'd like to do is have the PDF download the first time, and then when the user clicks on another link to the same file, the previously downloaded version opens rather than downloading the same file again.

Is this even possible?

Comment: HTTP cache headers instruct a browser that a response is cacheable. I have some doubts whether browsers will cache a 250MB response though, as that's pretty big. Maybe you shouldn't distribute 250MB pdf's. Seems pretty user-hostile.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but using a 3rd javascript library. Is that an option for you? Or you just want the browser to handle everything for you? It was not clear from your question what limitations you are under.

Comment: That is possible for us. What javascript library would you recommend? @Ryan